# Characteristic Function in the subset E

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb R$. Then the  characteristic function $\chi_{E}:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous if and only if

a) $E$ is closed.

b) $E$ is Open.

c) $E$ is both Open and Closed.

d) $E$ is neither Open Nor closed.

choose the correct options.

According to me, a) $E$ is closed,

because the function maps to only $0$ and $1$, so the range set is closed and function is continuous, the inverse mapping of closed set is closed, hence E is closed.

This is my argument, please correct me if my logic is wrong.

Comment: Well $\{0\}$ is closed. Do you think $\chi_{\{0\}}$ is continuous on $\mathbb {R}?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

$\chi_E$ is continuous iff the inverse image of any open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ under $\chi_E$ is open.

- If $0 \notin U$ and $1 \notin U$ then $\chi_E^{-1}(U) = \emptyset$ which is open.
- If $0 \in U$ and $1 \notin U$ then $\chi_E^{-1}(U) = \mathbb{R} \setminus E$ has to be open. So $E$ has to be closed.
- If $0 \notin U$ and $1 \in U$ then $\chi_E^{-1}(U) = E$ which therefore has to be open.
- If $0 \in U$ and $1 \in U$ then $\chi_E^{-1}(U) = \mathbb{R}$ which is open.

Conclusion $E$ has to be both open and closed, which is only possible when $E$ is equal to $\emptyset$ or to $\mathbb{R}$.

**Issue with what you did**

You were not considering all the closed sets to look at inverse image.

Comment: Thanks a lot..Nw I understood...the concept

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the answers, but I understood the concept clearly after my friend told me the explanation.

First, Characteristic function maps the element in domain to either $0$ or $1$, here if the element $x \in E$, then $\chi_{E}(x)=1$ and if the element $y$ is not in $E$, then $\chi_{E}(y)=0$. So $\{0,1\}$ is the range set.

Now $\{1\}$ is the closed set, since $\chi_{E}$ is continuous, "inverse mapping of closed set is closed" hence inverse image of $\{1\}$ which is the subset $E$, is closed.

Now $\{0\}$ is the closed set, since $\chi_{E}$ is continuous, "inverse mapping of closed set is closed" hence inverse image of $\{0\}$ which is the subset $E^c$, is closed.

According to the first argument, $E$ is closed so $E^c$ is open. According to the second argument, $E^c$ is closed so $E$ is open.

Hence $E$ should be both open and closed.

Comment: The only subsets of R that are both open and closed are R and the empty set.

Answer (score 2):

A late answer; still:

$\chi_E$ is continuous $\implies\forall x\in\Bbb R,\chi_E=1\ or\ \forall x\in\Bbb R,\chi_E=0$

Case 1: $\forall x\in\Bbb R,\chi_E=1\implies E=\Bbb R$

Case 2: $\forall x\in\Bbb R,\chi_E=0\implies E=\phi$

Both of which are open and closed (in fact, the only open and closed sets in $\Bbb R$)