# Continuous function from Sorgenfrey line to real line.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $\mathbb R_l$ be the Sorgenfrey line,$\mathbb R$ be the real line.

Describe a continuous function $f:\mathbb R_l\to \mathbb R$ such that $f:\mathbb{R\to R}$ is not continuous.

Does the function $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=1 $ if $x\geq 0$ work?

What about $f(x)=\ln|x|,x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$?

Comment: Just check the definition of continuity. Let $U$ be open in $\mathbb{R}$. You have the cases $U\cap\{0,1\}$ being empty, $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$ or $\{0,1\}$. In the first case $f(U)$ is empty, in the second it is $(-\infty,0)=\bigcup_{n<0}[n,0)$, in the third $[0,+\infty)=\bigcup_{n>0}[0,n)$ and in the third $\mathbb{R}_l$. All the results are open in $\mathbb{R}_l$

Comment: Any right continuous function would do.The question is from Munkres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove with no difficult that $[1,2)$ is a clopen set in Sorgenfrey line. Therefore $f:\mathbb{R}_{l}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \text{if} & x\in [1,2)\\ 
0 & \text{if} & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus[1,2)
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
is continuous (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297681/characteristic-function-in-the-subset-e) for reference). Clearly $f$ is not continuous when it is taked as $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Can you prove it? Hint: use limit characterization of continuity.

Edit: note that your example, $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\geq 0$ also works and is the same proof that have my answer. Your function is only the characteristic function of $[0,\infty)$, a clopen set in Sorgenfrey line.

Comment: alternatively, $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is not continuous since $\mathbb R$ is connected but $f(\mathbb R)=\{0,1\}$ is not.

Comment: For the case where $f$ is the characteristic function of $[1,\infty):$ If $C$ is $any$ subset of $\Bbb R$ then $f^{-1}C$ is open in $\Bbb R_l$ because $f^{-1}C\in \{\emptyset, (-\infty,0),[1,\infty),\Bbb R_l\}.$

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the function $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\ge0$ work?

Yes, it does. For me the easiest way to see it is continuous from $\mathbb R_l$ to $\mathbb R$ is to use the characterization of continuity "the preimage of every closed set is closed". Note that $f^{-1}(0)=(-\infty,0)$, and $f^{-1}(1)=[0,\infty)$,
and both $(-\infty,0)$ and $[0,\infty)$ are closed in $\mathbb R_l$. (Assuming basic open sets are half-open intervals of the form $[a,b).$)

2. What about $f(x)=\ln|x|,x\not=0$ and $f(0)=0$?

No, this one is not continuous, whether you think of is as a function from $\mathbb R_l$ or from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$. Note that $\frac1n\to0$ (both in $\mathbb R_l$ and in $\mathbb R$) but $f(\frac1n)\to-\infty$.

3. Combining ideas from 2 and 1 above,
   let $f(x)=\ln(-x),x<0$ and $f(x)=0, x\ge0$ (or, if you prefer, $f(x)=x, x\ge0$).

Then $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is not continuous since
$f(\frac{-1}n)\to-\infty$. But $f:\mathbb R_l\to\mathbb R$ is continuous. You could use that the restriction of $f$ to each of $(-\infty,0)$ and $[0,\infty)$ is continuous, and each of $(-\infty,0)$ and $[0,\infty)$ is a clopen (=closed-and-open) set. (Formally you could also involve the pasting lemma in the last step.)